# Modify a document with TinyXML

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

Right now, I save my data by simply rewriting the file requested by the user. The way my xml is structured is like this:

```
Skeleons root
    Skeleton with string name attribute
       bone with attributes
       bone with attributes
       bone with attributes
       bone with attributes
    end Skeleton
   Skeleton with string name attribute
       bone with attributes
       bone with attributes
       bone with attributes
       bone with attributes
    end Skeleton
    ....
   end Skeletons root
```

I iterate through to see if the skeleton of desired name exists and if it does I want to completely rewrite it. If not, I want to add it to the bottom of the root element.

Does anyone have an example of this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add a "bone" in either case? Or is it possible that you want to also modify an existing bone?

Comment: @ MSalters Nope I never want to modify an existing Bone, if the skeleton exists, overwrite it else create a new one at end of root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this is just a matter of splitting the steps.

First, define a `TiXmlElement *` and set it to 0. Iterate over all children of `Skeletons`. If you find the correct `Skeleton`, point your `TiXmlElement *` to it.

Secondly, if you haven't found it (`TiXmlElement *` still 0), create a new Skeleton and point your `TiXmlElement *` to it.

Finally, create a new bone underneath that `TiXmlElement *`.

Comment: I also need to clear the element of any old child bones, what method does this?